# Why is Strucker apprehensive about sending out “the twins”?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Why would Strucker be apprehensive about sending out the twins?

We saw a post credits scene from (will find this out) that showed Strucker quite proud of their accomplishments.

Is there some comic canon missing from the movie MCU that would create this apprehension? Or just plain paternal concern?

Answer (score 2):

No paternal concerns or other hidden plots. The reason -explained as you see the movie- is because Strucker trusted in his troops to stop Avenger's assault and when he saw this wouldn't be possible, execute the second plan which is *surrender* and delete all the files.

While List insisted that he has to deploy The Twins, he replied:

> They're not ready yet.

He's positive about the creation but remains the question whether they're volatile or not. In the previous film's post-credit scene, The Twins were highly unstable. Proud of the creation, not quite sure about deployment.

Answer (score -3):

He wasn't sure that they were under  Hydra's control yet because Magneto is so powerful  that he may have learned of the twins  and Hydra would have to try to defeat Magneto and also that Magneto had no longer the ability to control them once he found out they were alive.

Comment: However, there's no Magneto in the MCU.

Comment: Oops, good point. Then I go with my first statement of his fear to control their ability and not have them use it against them to escape besides Magneto might show up now course his son would be dead so I'd be kind of pointless but with the sale of Disney and Sony and blah blah blah blah you know there's no telling who's going to show up now I just hope they don't over do it too many characters could really throw things off

Comment: Magneto is unlikely to turn up until the rights to the X-Men universe come to Disney from 20th Century Fox.